# Making a flag with <div> and percentages

Tags: html, css, percentage

I need to make a flag with HTML and CSS.

I'm running into a few problems:

1. Each colour of the flag needs to be 33,3% of height.
2. The flag needs to stay the same shape when you change the size of the browser(it needs to fill the entire page).
3. The flag has a minimum width of 500px and a minimum height of 300px.

   ```css
   body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }

   #red {
     background-color: red;
     height: 33, 3%;
     width: 500px;
   }

   #white {
     background-color: white;
     height: 33, 3%;
     width: 500px;
   }

   #blue {
     background-color: blue;
     height: 33, 3%;
     width: 500px;
   }
   ```

   ```html
   <div id="red"></div>
   <div id="white"></div>
   <div id="blue"></div>
   ```

Comment: height: 33,3% its should be height:33.3% ?

Comment: What do you mean by a flag here? If you want to use a real flag, use img tag. Assuming that you refer to divs here I'm still not sure what you are asking for in your 'I'm running into a few problems:' section. Kindly rephrase your question.

Comment: TIp: Using 'px' for defining any measurements like heights/widths will not make your HTML elements responsive to the browser/device. Try to use % instead.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use background on the html element:

```css
html {
  min-height:300px;
  min-width:500px;
  height:100%;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red)   top,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom;
  background-size:100% 33.3%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: It's a flag containing three layers, so how can I do this with three colors?

Comment: Thank you, that did the job!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following code, please note:

- Wrap your markup in a div with id flag and set its size
- Measurements should be written as `33.3%`, you had few syntax errors
- min-width and min-height to set the minimum size of the element

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
  height: 33.3%;
  width: 500px;
}

#white {
  background-color: white;
  height: 33.3%;
  width: 500px;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 33.3%;
  width: 500px;
}

#flag {
  min-width: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flag">
  <div id="red"></div>
  <div id="white"></div>
  <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is, I can only use three divs. So it's not allowed to put a div around those three.

Comment: do you have access to the parent tag?

Answer (score 0):

The best and efficient way is to place all three div in a parent div and handle with that.
Here is the code snippet:

**CSS FILE:**

```
#red
{
    background-color: red;
    height: 33.3vh;
}
#white
{
    background-color: white;
    height: 33vh;
}
#blue
{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 33.3vh;  
}
#parent {
    min-height: 300px;
    min-width: 500px;
}
```

**HTML FILE**

```
<div id="parent">
 <div id="red"></div>
        <div id="white"></div>
        <div id="blue"></div>
</div>
```

And here is the working code link at Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y1jfby

Comment: Hey thank you for responding, the problem is that I am only allowed to use three divs and no more.

Comment: Checkout the updated code here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xoqvny

Comment: Thank you and haha yes CSS IS SEXY!